# Dynamically change row foreground color of particular cell in NatTable

Tags: java, nattable

do you have nay suggestions to dynamically change the color of cell , I have tried below but when table does not have the those label ("FAILURE") even after that row will remains colored. I want to revert back the color of colored cell when FAILURE label is not present in the table.

```
private static final String FAILURE = "FAILURE";
void example(){
final DefaultBodyLayerStack bodyLayer = underlyingLayer.getBodyLayer();



        // Custom label "FAILURE" for cell
        IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
            Integer rowCount = null;

            @Override
            public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels,
                    int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
                int rowIndex = bodyLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);

                for (GridConsoleRow gridConsoleRow : underlyingLayer.getBodyDataProvider().getList()) {
                    if (StringUtils.equals(gridConsoleRow.getLogLevel().trim(), FAILURE)) {
                            rowCount = bodyLayer.getPreferredRowCount()-1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (rowCount != null && rowIndex == rowCount.intValue()) {
                    configLabels.addLabel(FAILURE);
                    }
                }
            };
        bodyLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);

        // Custom style for label "FAILURE"
        natTable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
                Style cellStyle = new Style();
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(
                        CellStyleAttributes.FOREGROUND_COLOR,
                        GUIHelper.COLOR_RED);
                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                        CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle,
                        DisplayMode.NORMAL, FAILURE);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you debugged that the FAILURE label is really not present? NatTable only shows what it should, so if you registered the style with a red background only for the FAILURE label, it will only render rows in red that have that label. To be honest, I don't understand the logic of your `IConfigLabelAccumulator`. Probably the `rowCount` member is the cause, as you never set it back to `null` again if there is no failure. Not sure why you anyhow store that information in a member variable.